# Android Communication between activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I know the questions sounds very familiar on SO but I have different problem here is what I want to do.

1. Store Activity where user selects an item
2. Buy Activity here user will buy the selected item and calls downloader class and finish itself.
3. Downloader class here I download the content and from here I have to update progress bar on Store activity

**EDIT :**I am able to accomplish 1st and 2nd point but not 3rd one.

I searched a lot but didn't found a solution, any ideas how to accomplish this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I am not getting a single idea how to achieve this as I cant pass handler of Store Activity to Buy then to Downloader, nor can make the handler static that will create more problems and I dont like this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to **Vladimir Ivanov** for his inputs to help my problem although his approach is also correct but I find that method very complex for such a trivial task so here is how I solved the problem -

1. I started the But activity from Store using `startActivityForResult()`
2. When user buys item on Buy screen set some result that will tell us on on Store screen whether to start download or not.
3. Now in `onActivityResult()` of Store if result is positive I call the Downloader class passing handler to it

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a `Handler` in your activity, which is able to update the percent.
Then pass the instance of handler to the `Downloader`. When download percent is changed, create a message and send it to the handler.

Your Downloader should be a Service. Then you can pass a [`Messenger`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Messenger.html) instance through the startService().

Read more [here](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html&ei=hduvTamEF42TswaPx_3oCw&usg=AFQjCNH69MZ5ecq3l7PexAitL-u1vPr27g&sig2=7VdTjirnAcRE88dBO4IrOg). Feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt understand your answer have you read the question carefully

Comment: Hey. did you ask your question carefully? What exactly is your problem? Can you pass the info about selected item? Can't you download a file? Or may be you failed to update the download process?

Comment: I can pass the info of the object to be bought to Buy Activity what I am unable to do is update the download progress from Downloader class to Store class, sorry if I didnt frame the question clear.

Comment: Thanks, Yeah I also thought that but the problem is Download will start from Buy Activity and I have to make update on Store so how can I pass handler of Store to Downloader

Comment: Thanks for you time and valuable comments I didnt know about Messenger let me try on this